# get list of names if its same

Tags: php, pdo

I want to get nicknames of users with same IP adres that has registred a profile.
Now i understand that i need to make a if statement as if ip_adres count() > 1 echo the IP adres but how do i make the count of IP that equals.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT ip_adres, nickname2 FROM users";
$alias = $db->prepare($sql);
$alias->execute();

foreach($alias as $a){
    $ip_adres = $a['ip_adres'];
    $nickname = $a['nickname2'];
    if($ip_adres){
        echo "<pre>$nickname has a alias profile! $ip_adres</pre> ";
    }
}
?>
```

OUPUT

```
First has a alias profile! 213.93.99.38
Second has a alias profile! 213.93.99.38
Third has a alias profile! 213.93.45.33
Bla has a alias profile! 213.93.45.33
ZZZZ has a alias profile! 213.93
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT ip_adres, nickname2 FROM users";
$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

$ips = array();
$aliases = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    if (in_array($user['ip_adres'], $ips))
        $aliases[] = $user['ip_adres'];

    $ips[] = $user['ip_adres'];
}
if (empty($aliases)) {
    echo "Aliases not found";
}
else {
    foreach($users as $user) {
        if (in_array($user['ip_adres'], $aliases)) {
            echo $user['nickname2'] . ' has a alias profile! '. $user['ip_adres'] .'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i get both of the names displayed what alias it got ?

Comment: @Inna updated, check it

Comment: i get `Warning: uasort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in`

Comment: @Inna try `uasort( (array) $users, "cmp");`

Comment: now i get `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in`

Comment: @Inna ok, i updated answer, try without `usort`

Comment: the edited doesnt echo anything just blanco

Comment: @Inna maybe you don't have users with same ips, i updated answer, if it you will see `Aliases not found`

Comment: i copied the copied the code above and i dont get the Aliases not found! also

Comment: @Inna check you `error.log` or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at start page, after `<?php`

Comment: I dont get any errors, is it possible that the problem caused because seconds foreach loop has the same variables as the first one ? Im a beginner so i can't check much on this code :(

Comment: The first code was perfect it just overwrite the first `$user['nickname2']` so it showed only the second row.

Comment: @Inna i just now recheck code, he working. Don't know why you see blank page without any errors.

Comment: if i do `print_r($aliases);` above the second `foreach` i get the IP in array, if i do `print_r($aliases);` inside the second `foreach` it doesnst show any IP. Maybe it in there ?

Comment: @Inna try with brackets `{` `}`, i added in answer. It's very strange...

Comment: i think i know where the problem is, we do on the first foreach $users to $user so i think we need to use in the second foreach $user as $user, because than i get some arrays if i do print_r

Comment: Hmm now i get the data when i copied `$sql = "SELECT ip_adres, nickname2 FROM users";
$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();` above the second foreach.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your query and you will have your result for sure

```
select nickname2, count(ip_adres) as cnt from users group by nickname2 having cnt > 1;
```

good luck with that

Comment: Is the OP using MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: i get the error `.ip_adres' isn't in GROUP BY'`

Comment: delete ip_adres from select.

Comment: @Mouser so it is the issue with MSSQL right ?

Comment: @neo indeed. Nice solution, but tested it against MSSQL 2014 didn't work.

Comment: Just replace `HAVING cnt > 1` with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` and it will work in most databases. **Edit:** Having said that, grouping by nickname renders the query useless.