# list other alias name also

Tags: php, arrays

I want to show alias nickname which have 2 profiles on same IP-Address. 
Now i had one solution for this here on StackOverflow, now i want to display both of the names.

SOURCE

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT ip_adres, nickname2 FROM users";
$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

$ips = array();
$aliases = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    if (in_array($user['ip_adres'], $ips))
        array_push($aliases, $user);

    $ips[] = $user['ip_adres'];
}

foreach($aliases as $alias) {
    echo $alias['nickname2'] . ' has a alias profile! '. $alias['ip_adres'] .'<br/>';
}

?>
```

$user OURPUT

```
First has a alias profile! 213.93.99.38
Second has a alias profile! 213.93.99.38
Third has a alias profile! 213.93.45.33
Bla has a alias profile! 213.93.45.33
ZZZZ has a alias profile! 213.93
```

Now it shows

```
Second has a alias profile! 213.93.99.38
Bla has a alias profile! 213.93.45.33
```

I don't get the the first alias nickname how do I do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get list of names if its same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647746/get-list-of-names-if-its-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you..

```
<?php
require_once "db_connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT
       ip_adres,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nickname2 ORDER BY nickname2) nickname
       FROM
       users
       GROUP BY ip_adres
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

foreach($users as $u){
    $nick = $u['nickname'];
    $ip = $u['ip_adres'];
    echo "$nick $ip";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to something like this

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT ip_adres, nickname2 FROM users";
$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

$ips = array();

# count occurrences of each IP address
foreach($users as $user) {
    if (isset($ips[$user['ip_adres']]))
        $ips[$user['ip_adres']] ++;
    else
        $ips[$user['ip_adres']] = 1;
}

# print out records with IP address which appears more than once    
foreach($users as $user) {
    if (1 < $ips[$user['ip_adres']])
        echo $user['nickname2'] . ' has a alias profile! '. $user['ip_adres'] . '<br/>;
}
```

Comment: I don't get any echo with this

Comment: I've just added back the missing array declaration on line 6.

Comment: Also dont get the names with same IP can you check it